# Knockout notifySubscribers + Durandal = rapidly degrading performance?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I've built an app using DurandalJS - though I don't know if the framework is relevant here.  In Firefox and Chrome, if I click around the dark blue boxes (folders), the performance degrades quickly and I'm not sure why.  Every new folder I click on takes progressively longer to open - I can see it happening after about 20-30 folders are opened.

These folders are not being cached, and should be based on a singleton viewModel:

```
define(['services/dataservice', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'services/hub', 'viewmodels/setVm', 'viewmodels/folderVm'],
    function (dataservice, router, app, hub, SetViewModel, FolderViewModel) {
    // define vm
    return vm;
}
```

In the FF profiler, I see something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is meaningful to those of you more familiar with profiling, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this performance degradation would be occurring.

The memory profile in chrome shows a max memory consumption of about 45 MB, yet the time I have to wait for the page to draw does get progressively worse.

The live site is here:

[www.nogginator.com](http://www.nogginator.com)

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you looked at how much info you are caching in the browser?

Comment: @PWKad I've used the memory profiler (timeline and heap) in chrome, but everything seems to check out according to this guide:  http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/

Comment: What is the code commented out instead of "// define vm"?
Also, performance strongly depends of code in other referenced modules.

Comment: Not couting the mock class, there are almost 4k lines of code in your services and viewmodels. You definitely have a leak, but finding it is going to be difficult. Looking at it for a few minutes, my money would be on your use of jQuery droppable to bind to a common page class, creating a closure that can't be cleaned up properly. Honestly though, familiarizing myself enough with that much code is not a trivial task.

Comment: Hey, it would help if you could provide a repro of this issue with only the relevant code. Bounty or not, going through all the code on your site is a bit much for strangers ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem slow to me... How many folders do you open?

Comment: @alFReDNSH about 50-100.  Tyrsius took a deeper look at it yesterday and found that splitting up some of the larger files had a significant (positive) impact on garbage collection... I'm going to publish his changes to the live site this weekend and post back with an update.

Comment: Something that is supposed to be release actually is still in the notify list of some observable. Moreover, the dependence chain  increses awlays more. This explains both the memory consuption, and the slow down. 
Often this happens when there are unwished dependences. That is dependences that are not there by design, but just because knockout.js tracks automatically depependences. You do some computation involving an observable without the intention to create a dependence in some lost place of your code...but the dependence is created. That said it is very difficult discovering where

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem ended up being that too much stuff was in the `shell` viewmodel, stopping garbage collection from reclaiming it. Splitting it into several pieces made a significant performance impact.

Shell was split into

- A `authentication` service
- A `sidebar` viewmodel
- A `menu` viewmodel
- Some router configutation